# How to change "Quick Buy" title On product in shopify?

Tags: themes, shopify, translate

i  want to translate a shopify themes 
and I have a problem, I can not change the title 'quick buy' which appears in the product list, I look in every file of theme and no result

Answer (score 0):

You can find the options in the json file **en.default.json** (or similar) under *Locales* folder in the theme's HTML panel

JSON structure: `products -> general -> quick_buy_html`